# How do I install Ubuntu without a DE?

Tags: system-installation, desktop-environments

I want to get Ubuntu, but install a DE of my choice. Is there any way of getting a "blank" ubuntu and add the DE that I want?

Comment: Install the server edition.

Comment: Congratulations on your question reaching 10,000 views, along with the corresponding Gold Badge!  Side note - If the answer below helped you, you might consider marking it Accepted. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to start with a basic terminal and go from there. Fortunately, Ubuntu has a couple versions that are designed for practically exactly this:

- **[Ubuntu Server Edition](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)**
  Ubuntu Server can be installed on non-servers just fine, as a matter of fact. You'll get full UEFI support out-of-the-box and the capability to install X and whatever DM you want without the standard overhead.
- **[Ubuntu Minimal Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)**
  If you want to go even lighter, you can use the Minimal Edition, which is specially designed to only include the absolute core of Ubuntu. However, you lose the capability to run stuff like UEFI boot and other features, but they can be added if you want/try enough.

Both of these will give you just a shell (with Ubuntu Server giving you a bit more of a full stack if you don't want to mess around with things), and will allow you to install X and do whatever you please with a DM if that's the way you want to go.

Comment: Will the server version be able to do the same things as the non-server version?

Comment: @vojzzo Yep. Really, the server edition is just regular Ubuntu without X and some quality-of-life things that can be re-installed really easily, and are usually re-installed automatically.